# Getting a "DistributionNotFound" when running aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, boto

I'm trying to run the aws shell on a linux machine. Having installed aws and boto, I'm getting this error:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: boto
```

but boto is clearly installed, as shown in the pip freeze output. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/206) issue in github, and one answer there solved my problem, so I'm recording this for posterity:

```
pip uninstall boto
pip install -U gsutil
```